# Parsing JSON like format with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have two somewhat related questions regarding parsing a JSON like data format
using `pyparsing`. **The goal is to parse this data and convert the
result to JSON.**

**1)** The first type data looks like

```
mystr = """
    DataName = {
        fieldA = {
            fieldB = 10
            fieldC = "absf"
        }
    }
    DataName = {
        fieldA = {
            fieldB = 11
            fieldC = "bsf"
        }
    }
"""
```

I'm wondering what the best way to set up the grammar is, in order
to parse `mystr` into a list of dictionaries that would look like

```
expected_result = [{"DataName": {"fieldA": {"fieldB": 10, "fieldC": "absf"}}},
                   {"DataName": {"fieldA": {"fieldB": 11, "fieldC": "bsf"}}}]
```

My first attempt is as follows

```
from pyparsing import *
LBRACE, RBRACE, EQUAL = map(Suppress, "{}=")
field = Word(alphas + '[]')
string = dblQuotedString().setParseAction(removeQuotes)
number = pyparsing_common.number()

value = (string | number)
jobject = Forward()
memberDef = Group(field + EQUAL + value)
members = delimitedList(memberDef ^ jobject, delim=LineEnd())
jobject << Dict(field + EQUAL + LBRACE + Optional(members) + RBRACE)

members.parseString(mystr)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-70cbdee9640b> in <module>()
----> 1 members.parseString(mystr)

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseString(self, instring, parseAll)
   1204             instring = instring.expandtabs()
   1205         try:
-> 1206             loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
   1207             if parseAll:
   1208                 loc = self.preParse( instring, loc )

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1070             if self.mayIndexError or loc >= len(instring):
   1071                 try:
-> 1072                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1073                 except IndexError:
   1074                     raise ParseException( instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self )

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   2525         # pass False as last arg to _parse for first element, since we already
   2526         # pre-parsed the string as part of our And pre-parsing
-> 2527         loc, resultlist = self.exprs[0]._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
   2528         errorStop = False
   2529         for e in self.exprs[1:]:

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1070             if self.mayIndexError or loc >= len(instring):
   1071                 try:
-> 1072                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1073                 except IndexError:
   1074                     raise ParseException( instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self )

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   2587         for e in self.exprs:
   2588             try:
-> 2589                 loc2 = e.tryParse( instring, loc )
   2590             except ParseException as err:
   2591                 err.__traceback__ = None

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in tryParse(self, instring, loc)
   1112     def tryParse( self, instring, loc ):
   1113         try:
-> 1114             return self._parse( instring, loc, doActions=False )[0]
   1115         except ParseFatalException:
   1116             raise ParseException( instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1070             if self.mayIndexError or loc >= len(instring):
   1071                 try:
-> 1072                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1073                 except IndexError:
   1074                     raise ParseException( instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self )

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   2799     def parseImpl( self, instring, loc, doActions=True ):
   2800         if self.expr is not None:
-> 2801             return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
   2802         else:
   2803             raise ParseException("",loc,self.errmsg,self)

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1070             if self.mayIndexError or loc >= len(instring):
   1071                 try:
-> 1072                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1073                 except IndexError:
   1074                     raise ParseException( instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self )

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   2799     def parseImpl( self, instring, loc, doActions=True ):
   2800         if self.expr is not None:
-> 2801             return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
   2802         else:
   2803             raise ParseException("",loc,self.errmsg,self)

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1070             if self.mayIndexError or loc >= len(instring):
   1071                 try:
-> 1072                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1073                 except IndexError:
   1074                     raise ParseException( instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self )

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   2542                     raise ParseSyntaxException( ParseException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self) )
   2543             else:
-> 2544                 loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
   2545             if exprtokens or exprtokens.haskeys():
   2546                 resultlist += exprtokens

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1070             if self.mayIndexError or loc >= len(instring):
   1071                 try:
-> 1072                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1073                 except IndexError:
   1074                     raise ParseException( instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self )

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   3004     def parseImpl( self, instring, loc, doActions=True ):
   3005         try:
-> 3006             loc, tokens = self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
   3007         except (ParseException,IndexError):
   3008             if self.defaultValue is not _optionalNotMatched:

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1070             if self.mayIndexError or loc >= len(instring):
   1071                 try:
-> 1072                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1073                 except IndexError:
   1074                     raise ParseException( instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self )

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   2525         # pass False as last arg to _parse for first element, since we already
   2526         # pre-parsed the string as part of our And pre-parsing
-> 2527         loc, resultlist = self.exprs[0]._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
   2528         errorStop = False
   2529         for e in self.exprs[1:]:

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1070             if self.mayIndexError or loc >= len(instring):
   1071                 try:
-> 1072                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1073                 except IndexError:
   1074                     raise ParseException( instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self )

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   2587         for e in self.exprs:
   2588             try:
-> 2589                 loc2 = e.tryParse( instring, loc )
   2590             except ParseException as err:
   2591                 err.__traceback__ = None

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in tryParse(self, instring, loc)
   1112     def tryParse( self, instring, loc ):
   1113         try:
-> 1114             return self._parse( instring, loc, doActions=False )[0]
   1115         except ParseFatalException:
   1116             raise ParseException( instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1070             if self.mayIndexError or loc >= len(instring):
   1071                 try:
-> 1072                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1073                 except IndexError:
   1074                     raise ParseException( instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self )

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   2799     def parseImpl( self, instring, loc, doActions=True ):
   2800         if self.expr is not None:
-> 2801             return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
   2802         else:
   2803             raise ParseException("",loc,self.errmsg,self)

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1076                 loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1077
-> 1078         tokens = self.postParse( instring, loc, tokens )
   1079
   1080         retTokens = ParseResults( tokens, self.resultsName, asList=self.saveAsList, modal=self.modalResults )

/home/matthew/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyparsing.py in postParse(self, instring, loc, tokenlist)
   3247                 tokenlist[ikey] = _ParseResultsWithOffset(tok[1],i)
   3248             else:
-> 3249                 dictvalue = tok.copy() #ParseResults(i)
   3250                 del dictvalue[0]
   3251                 if len(dictvalue)!= 1 or (isinstance(dictvalue,ParseResults) and dictvalue.haskeys()):

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

This does not work, however I am unclear why. `mystr` is a `delimitedList` of
two `jobject`s (`DataName`s) where each `jobject` contains 1 `jobject`
(`fieldA`) which is comprised of 1 `members` which has two `memberDefs`.
What am I missing here?

Alternatively, I could define my grammar as follows

```
value = Forward()
jobject = Forward()
value << (string | number | Group(jobject))
memberDef = Group(field + EQUAL + value)
members = delimitedList(memberDef, delim=LineEnd())
jobject << Dict(LBRACE + Optional(members) + RBRACE)
res = members.parseString(mystr)
```

I can then iterate through the results and generate dictionaries, however this
feels like a bit of a kludge.

```
list_of_dicts = []
for pair in res:
    list_of_dicts.append({pair[0]: pair[1].asDict()})

print(list_of_dicts)
[{'DataName': {'fieldA': {'fieldC': 'absf', 'fieldB': 10.0}}}, {'DataName': {'fieldA': {'fieldC': 'bsf', 'fieldB': 11.0}}}]
```

**2)** The data format also includes text like the following.

```
mystr2 = """
fieldA = {
    someFieldA[] = {
    }
    someFieldB[] = {
        "typeA", "typeB"
    }
    someFieldC[] = {
        fieldData = {
            data = 10
        }
        fieldData = {
            data = 12
        }
    }
    someFieldD = "bsf"
}
fieldA = {
}
"""
```

I would like to parse this into a list of dictionaries as follows

```
expected_result2 = [{"fieldA": {"someFieldA": [],
                               "someFieldB": ["typeA", "typeB"],
                               "someFieldC":[{"fieldData": {"data": 10}},
                                             {"fieldData": {"data": 10}}],
                               "someFieldD": "bsf"}},
                    {"fieldA": {}}]
```

I attempted to address this by adding an `array` type to the grammar

```
value = Forward()
jobject = Forward()

arrayElements = delimitedList(string)
array = Group(LBRACE + Optional(arrayElements, []) + RBRACE)

value << (string | number | Group(jobject) | array)
memberDef = Group(field + EQUAL + value)
members = delimitedList(memberDef, delim=LineEnd())
jobject << Dict(LBRACE + Optional(members) + RBRACE)

res2 = members.parseString(mystr2)
print(res2)
 [['fieldA', [['someFieldA[]', []], ['someFieldB', ['typeA', 'typeB']], ['someFieldC[]', [['fieldData', [['data', 10.0]]], ['fieldData', [['data', 12.0]]]]], ['someFieldD', 'bsf']]], ['fieldA', []]]
```

This returns a parseResult however I am unsure how to go about transforming
that into something like `expected_result2`. In addition, there is nothing in the grammar above to distinguish between elements of the form

```
Data = {
}
```

and

```
Data[] = {
}
```

which should map to `{"Data": {}}` and `{"Data": []}` respectively.

### Edit

There was a typo in `mystr2` above, `someFieldB[] = {` had been improperly written as `someFieldB = {`

A grammar which accounts for the significance of `[]`, is shown below.

```
LBRACE, RBRACE, EQUAL = map(Suppress, "{}=")
field = Word(alphas)
string = dblQuotedString().setParseAction(removeQuotes)
number = pyparsing_common.number()
scalar_value = (string | number)

value_list = Forward()
jobject = Forward()

memberDef1 = Group(field + EQUAL + scalar_value)
memberDef2 = Group(field + EQUAL + jobject)
memberDef3 = Group(field + "[]" + EQUAL + LBRACE + value_list + RBRACE)
memberDef = memberDef1 | memberDef2 | memberDef3

value_list << (delimitedList(string, ",") | ZeroOrMore(memberDef2))
members = delimitedList(memberDef, delim=LineEnd())
jobject << Dict(LBRACE + Optional(members, '{}') + RBRACE)
res = members.parseString(mystr2)
```

which appears to properly parse, however I am still unclear how I would go about transforming `res` into a list of dictionaries?

### Edit 2

An actual example illustrating the grammar is included below

```
HistoricalDataRequest = {
    securities[] = {
        "SPY US Equity", "TLT US Equity"
    }
    fields[] = {
        "PX_LAST"
    }
    startDate = "20150629"
    endDate = "20150630"
    overrides[] = {
    }
}

HistoricalDataResponse = {
    securityData = {
        security = "SPY US Equity"
        eidData[] = {
        }
        sequenceNumber = 0
        fieldExceptions[] = {
        }
        fieldData[] = {
            fieldData = {
                date = 2015-06-29
                PX_LAST = 205.420000
            }
            fieldData = {
                date = 2015-06-30
                PX_LAST = 205.850000
            }
        }
    }
}

HistoricalDataResponse = {
    securityData = {
        security = "TLT US Equity"
        eidData[] = {
        }
        sequenceNumber = 1
        fieldExceptions[] = {
        }
        fieldData[] = {
            fieldData = {
                date = 2015-06-29
                PX_LAST = 118.280000
            }
            fieldData = {
                date = 2015-06-30
                PX_LAST = 117.460000
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is inconsistency between the original data and what you want to have as output. On one hand, you want to convert `fieldB = 10\n fieldC = "absf"` to a dictionary. On the other hand, you want to convert an identical construct `DataName = {...}\n DataName = {...}` into a list of one-element dictionaries. Does it happen that DataName indeed gets repeated, or is it DataNameA, DataNameB in the original data?

Comment: Ah, actually I see now: the first example is a subcase of the second example, with the root element sort of having `[]` at the end.

Comment: Yes that's correct, sorry for the ambiguity. The `[]` indicates a list, which from analyzing the format can either be a comma separated list of strings as in `someFieldB = {\n"typeA", "typeB"\n}` or a list of `\n` separated dictionaries as in `someFieldC[] = {\n fieldData = {\n data = 10\n }\n fieldData = {\n data = 12\n}\n`

Comment: If the "[]" suffix is significant for determining the definition of an array of values, then you shouldn't bury it in the definition of `field`. Instead, declare `field + EQUAL + value` separate from `field + "[]" + EQUAL + value_list`. Then define `value_list` as `delimitedList(scalarValue) | OneOrMore(jobject)` where `scalar_value = string | number`

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Thanks, great library by the way. I have edited my question to include your feedback. Is there a way to allow `value_list` to be empty and to set the default in this case to `[]`? i.e. strings of the form `myValue[] = {}`? I attempted to use `ZeroOrMore` instead of `OneOrMore` but this doesn't appear to support a `default` parameter?

Comment: Are you designing this format, or is it given to you? When you have a list of `jobject`, why are the defined with multiple `field = jobject` expressions, all with the same field name? Why aren't they just `{jobject jobject jobject}`? I pretty much have a working parser using `ParseResults.asDict`, save for this part. The multiple entries with the same key get collapsed to a single entry, since keys in a dict can be duplicates. For instance, why isn't `somefieldC` just `someFieldC[] = {
        {
            data = 10
        }
        {
            data = 12
        }
    }`

Comment: This is a given format. These are the string representations of requests and
responses to a data service which would be logged to a file. I agree that the 
multiple `field = jobject` with the same field name is undesirable for
translating this into a dictionary, hence why I thought I could translate it
into a list of dictionaries. An alternative possibility would be to just drop
this information since as you point out it seems unnecessary. I have edited my
question to include an actual request response for more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, with some finagling and shenanigans, I think I have contrived a parser that can give you JSON-able dicts from this format.

```
LBRACE, RBRACE, EQUAL = map(Suppress, "{}=")
field = Word(alphas, alphas+'_')
# was field = Word(alphas)
string = dblQuotedString().setParseAction(removeQuotes)
number = pyparsing_common.number()
date_expr = Regex(r'\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d')
scalar_value = (string | date_expr | number)
# was scalar_value = (string | number)

list_marker = Suppress("[]")
value_list = Forward()
jobject = Forward()

memberDef1 = Group(field + EQUAL + scalar_value)
memberDef2 = Group(field + EQUAL + jobject)
memberDef3 = Group(field + list_marker + EQUAL + LBRACE + value_list + RBRACE)
memberDef = memberDef1 | memberDef2 | memberDef3

value_list <<= (delimitedList(scalar_value, ",") | ZeroOrMore(Group(Dict(memberDef2))))
value_list.setParseAction(lambda t: [ParseResults(t[:])])

members = OneOrMore(memberDef)
jobject <<= Dict(LBRACE + ZeroOrMore(memberDef) + RBRACE)
# force empty jobject to be a dict
jobject.setParseAction(lambda t: t or {})

parser = members
parser = OneOrMore(Group(Dict(memberDef)))

tests = [mystr, mystr2]

import pprint
import json
for test in tests:
    print(test)
    res = parser.parseString(test)
    for res_dict in res:
        pprint.pprint(res_dict.asDict())
        # or convert to JSON using:
        # print(json.dumps(res_dict.asDict(), indent=2))
    print('')
```

prints (adding empty `jobject` for `someFieldE` and empty list for `someFieldF`):

```
{'DataName': {'fieldA': {'fieldB': 10, 'fieldC': 'absf'}}}
{'DataName': {'fieldA': {'fieldB': 11, 'fieldC': 'bsf'}}}

{'fieldA': {'someFieldA': [],
            'someFieldB': ['typeA', 'typeB'],
            'someFieldC': [{'a': {'data': 10}}, {'a': {'data': 12}}],
            'someFieldD': 'bsf',
            'someFieldE': {},
            'someFieldF': []}}
```

I worked around the multiple dict keys using `Group`'s around `Dict`'s, so that the duplicate keys would be isolated into separate `ParseResults`. The parse action on `value_list` is there so that empty lists return empty `ParseResults` in a list. I had to force empty `jobject`s to become dicts, because leaving them as empty `ParseResults` will not have any keys, and so won't return a dict from `asDict()`.

(Edit: To accommodate your posted example, I had to add '_' as a valid field name character, and also define a new `date_expr` type for the date-like field values.)

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed response. Upon further inspection of my data, I realised a `field` can actually contain spaces as well, e.g. `Security Description = "COQ7 Comdty"`. I attempted to solve this adding a `' '` to the `bodyChars` of `Word`, i.e. `field = Word(alphas, alphas+'_'+' ')` however this then matches the trailing space before the `=`.  I have been fumbling around with `Regex` but can't seem to get the right expression

Comment: Probably the simplest is to add `str.rstrip` as a parse action to `field` to strip the trailing spaces: `field = Word(printables+' ', excludeChars='=');
field.addParseAction(tokenMap(str.rstrip))`

Comment: Or do this to convert to nice Pythonic identifiers: `field.addParseAction(tokenMap(str.rstrip), tokenMap(str.lower), tokenMap(str.replace, ' ', '_'))`